# PC doesn't boot on better PSU

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, gpu

I have Dell Optiplex 330 DT PC and recently I changed my GPU ATI Radeon 2400XT DDR2 256MB with Gigabyte GT 710 GDDR5 2GB and the sound started to crackle. In my opinion, it's obvious that it's PSU fault. So, I tried PSU from the different PC [(see here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wI0N.jpg) but my PC doesn't boot on it. The HD starts but no motherboard logo, just LEDs are lighting I. I can also use power button to turn on/off these lights but no logo on the screen. Dell PSU:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdExR.jpg)
Where is the problem? I don't want to buy a new PC because I spent money for GPU. What would be the most clever step in my case?

I also noticed that original Dell PSU doesn't have 4 pin connector and has only 24 pin connector. The other PSU has both 4 pin and 24 pin connectors. Both PSUs have 23 wires on 24 pin connector (I'm not really sure why but connectors with 24 holes has one hole empty, without contact and wire).

Comment: It's probably a proprietary PSU with non-standard pinout, it's pretty common with Dells. However, I don't understand how you came to the conclusion that sound problems after GPU change are caused by faulty PSU.

Comment: Thank you for comment. The PSU from the other PC has the same pinout + additional 4 pin connector. On Ati-2400 XT there are no such sound problems. On Gigabyte sound crackles when watching YouTube. Sound crackles a lot from youtube at the moments when I adjust slider with the mouse wheel in photo editing program. Ati requires 40W and Gigabyte 95W. Another version - faulty GPU.

Comment: "_and the sound started to crackle_" - does this refer to audio output from the sound card, or that the phyiscal system started making crackling sounds?

Comment: Presuming your graphics card is a [GV-N710D5-2GL](https://www.gigabyte.com/uk/Graphics-Card/GV-N710D5-2GL#ov), the recommended power supply is 300W+, so a PSU upgrade is a sensible idea. However, as @gronostaj mentioned, [Dell have a reputation of swapping their ATX pinout](https://www.smps.us/power-connectors.html), though yours [appears to be standard](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/845088/Dell-Optiplex-330.html?page=77).

Comment: @Attie Output from the sound card. I even tried an external soundcard via USB, the same thing was happening. A bit strange because I use only one HD. And why an other PSU doesn't work on Dell, I've not idea (doesn't boot  the motherboard, but the LEDs of the motherboard are lighting).